# Pandas: DataFrame.apply returning series instead of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I am applying a function on a dataframe `df` and that function returns a dataframe `int_df`, but the result is getting stored as a series.

df

```
  limit
0  4
```

new_df

```
  A  B
0 0  Number
1 1  Number
2 2  Number
3 3  Number
```

This is a pseudocode of what I have done:

```
def foo(x):
    
    limit = x['limit']
    int_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B']) # Create empty dataframe

    # Append a new row to the dataframe
    for i in range(0, limit):
        int_df.loc[len(int_df.index)] = [i, 'Number']

    return int_df # This is dataframe

new_df = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
new_df # This is a series but I need a dataframe
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: you're getting a series of dataframe. You're applying the function to each row, and you're returning the dataframe for each row.

Comment: could you [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) what are you trying to do? you don't need `apply` to append a rows

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, I have added an explanation. I need to take value from `df`, and use it inside function `foo()` to create another dataframe called `int_df`. `foo()` is supposed to return a dataframe but it returns a series.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df = df.limit.apply(range).explode().to_frame('A').assign(B='number')
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
  A  B
0 0  Number
1 1  Number
2 2  Number
3 3  Number
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is a pseudocode of my original code. So I need that function to return a dataframe.

Comment: @Animeartist Seems like you just wanna explore the dataframe based on the 'limit' column and add a new column. Which can be done via range/explode without any function. you can update your sample `inp/out` dataframe to be more specific about the requirement.

Comment: Sorry, actually few other operations are also performed to get the `int_df`. All of those steps are not shown in the post.

Comment: Ok. So, there's one more option that may work for you. You can initialize an empty list. Then, instead of returning the df, You can add the `df` to that list. After that, use `pd.concat`. This way you'll get the dataframe.

Comment: Problem is, the apply function is returning a series and not a dataframe. So we cannot perform pd.concat() in the end.

Comment: `pd.concat` works on Series as well as DataFrames.

Comment: @Animeartist  you can try `pd.concat(df.apply(foo, axis=1).tolist())` maybe

Comment: @Ben.T, Thankyou so much for the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for!